# Getting only 7 faces out of 13 using google face_detection in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I am using Python to do face detection using Google Vision API. But after setting `max_results` I am getting only 7 faces out of 13.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

response = client.face_detection(image=image)
faces = response.face_annotations
print(len(faces))

Comment: response = client.annotate_image({'image': {'source': {'image_uri':'gs://bucket_name/File.jpg'}}, 'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION,'max_results':40}],})

Comment: Added max_results with above satement - still i am getting 7 faces.

Comment: Very good, now please post this code in your question.